# How can I add a time stamp to a file name uploaded with $_File before the file extension

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
$image_path = $_FILES["p_image"]["name"].time();
```

it names the file `image02.jpg1335279888`

but i want it to be named `image02_1335279888.jpg`

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["p_image"]["name"]);
$image_path = $path_parts['filename'].'_'.time().'.'.$path_parts['extension']
```

Comment: @user521180 If you're doing this so 2 files with the same name don't overwrite one another, then you may consider using microtime(true); instead of the time(). Otherwise 2 images uploaded with the same name in the same second will overwrite. Consider a single user uploading 2 images both called "image.jpg".

Comment: You'll also need to add the underscore in there too, in order to get the exact naming convention mentioned in your original post: $image_path = $path_parts['filename']."_".microtime(true).'.'.$path_parts['extension'];

Answer (score 1):

You can check this one:

```
$file = $_FILES["p_image"]["name"];
$array = explode('.', $file);
$fileName=$array[0];
$fileExt=$array[1];
$newfile=$fileName."_".time().".".$fileExt;
```

Comment: Should that not be `$newfile=$filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $fileExt;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$image_path = $_FILES["p_image"]["name"];
$extension = pathinfo($image_path)['extension'];
$file = "image02_".time().".".$extension."";
echo $file;
```

Output:

> *image02_1641041826.jpg*

Comment: It would be great if you could explain what the code does~