# Upload files with same name but different time and date?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Is it possible in PHP, when you upload a file in SQL database to keep the name of the file, but behind that name and extension to append time and date, so that you upload the file with the same name but with different time and date?

Example:

```
$newName=date().'/'.time().$extension;
```

In this case I just want to keep the names of the files original and same  but change only the date of upload. Example :

```
$newName= $extension.date().'/'time();
```

I know this above will not work, but I took it just as an example!

Comment: The answer to your question will most likely be "yes". Would that help you? doubt that.. Have you considered adding the code you already have, so that we can help you improve your code to solve that problem?

Comment: sorry i will upload  it so that i can be clear

Comment: Just add `date("Y-m-d h:i:s")` after the filename

Comment: @Andreas so you get for example the name like this :

Comment: @Andreas "somenamedatetime.jpg "  the number will be displayed after the name ! in my case i want to avoid the date and time and just keep the name and extesnion

Comment: Then move the date to before the extension for crying out loud.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a time stamp to a file name uploaded with $\_File before the file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300690/how-can-i-add-a-time-stamp-to-a-file-name-uploaded-with-file-before-the-file-e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use explode method for add date time in your file name kindly look below.

```
$file_name_array = explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']));
$file_name_for_store = $file_name_array[0].date('y-m-d H:i:s').$file_name_array[0];
```

Now you can upload your file with `$file_name_for_store` and store it also in database.